# How to get all outbound links on current web page from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink

I am working on a code wherein I need to scan and get a list of all outbound links from the web page open in the current active tab. This has to be achieved by simply clicking my extension. I am looking to write this code in javascript, but so far have not been able to find anywhere to start. Can someone please point me in the right direction and help me with this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step 1: Do you know JavaScript?

Comment: Yes I do know basic regular javascript. js tailored to use chrome extensions is a different matter but I am getting started with it. Next Step?

Comment: Step 2: Do some searches to become familiar with Chrome Extentions.  This should eventually lead you to one of the most valuable resources for this topic.  [developer.chrome.com](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

Comment: How did you go with this extension?  Would certainly love to help you get it into prod.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Get all href links in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922899/get-all-href-links-in-dom)

Basically they use the following code to create an array of the links of the page:

```
var array = [];
var links = document.links;
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
  array.push(links[i].href);
}
```

For creating the chrome extension try reading: http://coryg89.github.io/technical/2013/08/13/how-to-create-your-own-chrome-extensions/
, which is a good guide to do so.

This looks like what you need. Good luck!

Comment: I haven't tried this code yet but it seems to me that if I did try it, wouldn't it try and get me the links from the page running in my extension instead of the webpage in the current tab???

Comment: Read the link first then respond... I'll be heree

Comment: Thanks the link was great and even though I have already made a basic "Hello World" sort of extension, the page was still informative. The code that you sent me, have you tried it yourself in an extension? And can you please answer me: would this code really work because how do I make the extension understand it has to find the links from the current tab's web[age and not its own background page??

Comment: Have you tried to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) ?