# Chrome Extension to grab certain links from a page if they contain a keyword and opening them all in new tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension to go through this process:

1. Grab all links containing XYZ keyword in the URL
2. Take the XYZ containing links and make a slight change to the URL
3. Open all new links in new tabs

I know a little Python and have found the following relating to JS:

[Get all href links in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922899/get-all-href-links-in-dom)

Is this slightly on the right track? Or will I need to look at a different route?

I've created Chrome extensions that take a selection of text and open a new tab with a custom URL using that text but can't find exactly what I'm looking for in any documentation for this project

Thanks in advance to everyone :)

Comment: You'll need two scripts: [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that will find the links, extract the URLs, and send them in a [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) that will use [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) to create the tabs.

Comment: Ah ha, that makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you set on it being an extension within Chrome?

If I could propose an alternative, use Python plus Selenium. Selenium is a web automation library that can be easily customized to pull every link (searches for "a href" tags) into an array which you can then iterate through for your keyword.

Upon a match, you can modify it however and open it up in a new tab within the automated driver.

Comment: Thanks for the response salvo! Unfortunately, I've gotta stick with a Chrome Extension due to distributing it to a few colleagues that need it to be as easy as possible. I am looking into using Selenium for a few other projects now that you've put the idea in my mind :) cheers!